# How to test Here Map Android SDK Navigation

Tags: android, here-api

Using **HERE Mobile SDK** for Android, we tried to test the navigation and created a GPS Feeder for mock locations. We get different results using position manager vs navigation

Using the position manager, we tracked the location as in this image
([click here](http://vds.stuffwedo.eu/dev/driver/HereMapPositionCoordinates(NoNavigation).png))

Using the position listener from the navigation manager
([click here](http://vds.stuffwedo.eu/dev/driver/HereMapNavigationPositionCoordinates.png))

We also tried with **HERE WeGo Android App** from Android Play Store, and we had the same issues.
But using Google Navigation, this issue didn't happen.

Do you know any other solution for Navigation testing?

Answer (score 0):

Best for testing your navigation is to use **navigationManager.simulate(navigationRoute, 60);** Then you will be driving along the route, however, you cannot test how the route is being recalculated in case you don't follow the route.

Comment: This was the Plan B, where we send start and finish coordinates. But we really wanted to simulate more close to real life scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to real testing means when you are moving and navigation updates you then you have to use `navigationManager.startNavigation(route)` instead of `navigationManager.simulate(navigationRoute, 50);`